# Schengen Visa - Date of Departure after first intended stay

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, italy

I am apply for a Schengen Visa for Italy.  I know I will be there for one year for business.  During that time period I will be required to travel periodically for work or fly back to the US for a holiday.  How do I answer the question, "Intended date of departure from the Schengen area after the first intended stay."  I don't know what dates I may be required to travel.

Comment: Are you applying for a Schengen Type-C "Business" visa or a Type-D "Work" visa? It seems like you may be applying for the former, but your description of wanting to effectively stay for a year would make the latter more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you.  It appears I should be applying for a Type D work visa.  I appreciate your response to my question.

Answer (score 2):

You must apply for an Italian D-Visa (Long term/Residence permit) that allows you to work.

A Schengen C-Visa (Short term) only allows 90 days in a 180 period.

As part of your Business, state you you must travel periodically back to the US. That should be no problem.

Comment: Thank you.  It appears I should be applying for a Type D work visa.  I appreciate your response to my question.

Comment: @JoyceRaesner And remember that such visas are National Visas, so look and see if special agreements with Italy exist with your country of citizenship.